# NodeJS: How to stop a web server?

Tags: node.js, gulp, webserver, electron, node-webkit

I'm using the plugin [gulp-server-livereload](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-server-livereload).

```
var server = require('gulp-server-livereload');
gulp.src(pathDir).pipe(server({
   livereload: true,
   directoryListing: true,
   open: true,
   port: 80
}));
```

How to stop the server?

I tried server.restart(), server.kill(), server.reset()

But always there are such errors:

> Uncaught Error: listen EADDRINUSE 127.0.0.1:35729
>       at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
>       at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1045:20)
>       at Server._listen2 (net.js:1262:14)
>       at listen (net.js:1298:10)
>       at doListening (net.js:1397:7)
>       at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.asyncCallback [as callback] (dns.js:62:16)
>       at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:81:1

0)

Please help me to solve my question or tell me another option how you can 
implement what I need.

Comment: Why did you tag [tag:electron] and [tag:node-webkit], when is your gulpfile loaded and did you closed all previous process because the error says the port 35729 is already in use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error is occurring because of another process using the port. It is likely just a previous instance of this process, however it is possible that another application is using the port.

You will be unable to stop this using Node, as it is a process remaining from another run and processes do not have the permissions to 'manage' one another.

On Windows use task manager to kill the node process, on Mac you can use Activity Monitor, and on Unix/Linux you can use htop or similar.

---

Alternatively on Unix/Linux (incl. MacOS) you can use

```
sudo lsof -i :35729
```

to find the process id of the process ID using that port, then kill it:

```
kill -9 {PID}
```

---

To ensure your node server cleanly shuts down in future add event handlers:

```
process.on('SIGTERM', ..)

process.on('uncaughtException', ..)
```

and invoke code inside these to shut down your application.

Comment: How to do it? I'm writing server.exit (). But the output is an error: Uncaught TypeError: server.exit is not a function

Comment: I do not need to kill the whole process, but only gulp-server-livereload. The process itself should work, I need to specify a different directory for gulp-server-livereload.

Comment: The port is in use - so you need to kill the previous running instance

Comment: This or another application does use this specific port.